# Why does `dict_display` allow duplicate keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't mean because the standard says so, but the rationale for it. The specification says:

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary: each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the corresponding datum. This means that you can specify the same key multiple times in the key/datum list, and the final dictionary’s value for that key will be the last one given.

This means that it's perfectly legal to form a `dict` by:

```
d = { 'a': 1, 'b':2, 'b':3 }
```

However I hardly see any reason why one would like to define it that way, most often I'd guess that was a mistake. If you compare keyword arguments to a function the corresponding construct is forbidden.

Is there a good way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

This "bug" had been reported, discussed and finally rejected - see https://bugs.python.org/issue16385.

The main reasons specified by the rejectors were that

> A code generator could depend on being able to write duplicate keys without having to go back and erase previous output.

and that

> An error is out of the question for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-May/040081.html), which raises this point:

```
d = {spam(a): 'a', spam(b): 'BB', spam(c): 'Ccc'}
```

Which not only highlights that this must be a runtime thing, but also that there are cases where you might want to allow it. For example, when code is being generated, or for dict comprehensions which overwrite defaults, etc.

```
defaults = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
specific = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
combined = {key: val for key, val in itertools.chain(defaults.items(), specific.items())}
```

As a personal note, it also fits well with `.update`, which adds or updates a key, not complaining when it already exists.

As for a way to prevent this, when keys are valid python keywords, you can use:

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2, b=3)
```

You can of course make your own wrapper, but it'll look ugly:

```
def uniqdict(items):
    dct = {}
    for key, val in items:
        if key in dct:
            raise KeyError('key {0:} already exists'.format(key))
        dct[key] = val
    return dct

uniqdict((('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least several cases where you might use this behavior of a `dict` accepting multiple identical keys because the [dictionary display is now evaluated left to right](http://bugs.python.org/issue11205).

1) If multiple keys evaluate to the same output, but you only want to take the last instance.

For example, imagine you want to display a number if it's even or else 'odd'; you could use dictionary:

```
def f(n):
    return {True: n, n % 2: 'odd'}[True]
```

Of course there are more readable ways for this example, like using an if-else clause, but it illustrates the point.

2) With `OrderedDict`, taking advantage of this behavior is the recommended way to remove duplicates from a list while preserving the order, as [Raymond Hettinger says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835527/6260170). For example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(['a','b','d','d','a']))
# ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

If you are concerned about the behavior then you should simply check your keys are unique before building the dictionary, for example `assert len(keys) == len(set(keys))`. Of you could check the key is not in the dictionary before adding it, `if key not in my_dict: my_dict[key] = value`.